# How to concatenate two rows into one in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have a table which has such kind of records

```
ID wk category mo tu wedn
1   1   3       4   4  4
1   1   4       5   5  5
1   1   18      7   7  7
1   2   3       4   4  4
1   2   4       5   5  5
1   2   17      2   2  2
```

How do I concatenate rows have same category and keep the non-matched rows from either wk=1 and wk=2 as well into something like the following
and data from wk=1 are required in from of data from wk=2:

```
ID  category mo tu wedn mo2 tu2 wedn2
1       3    4   4   4   4   4   4
1       4    5   5   5   5   5   5
1       18   7   7   7   0   0   0
1       17   0   0   0   2   2   2
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you just interested in wk=1 and wk=2, or do you want to generalize this to wk=n? If it's just wk=1 and wk=2, simply left join the table to itself twice filtering by wk=1 and wk=2, respectively, and group by. If it's wk=n, what you want to produce is called a "pivot table" or "crosstab report". Google that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a full outer join, and use `wk` to distinguish which rows goes to what side - left or right:

```
select
    NVL(a.id, b.id)
,   NVL(a.category, b.category)
,   NVL(a.mo, 0)
,   NVL(a.tu, 0)
,   NVL(a.wedn, 0)
,   NVL(b.mo, 0) as mo2
,   NVL(b.tu, 0) as tu2
,   NVL(b.wedn, 0) as wedn2
from MyTable a
full outer join MyTable b ON a.id=b.id AND a.wk=1 AND b.wk=2 AND a.category=b.category
where (a.wk is null or a.wk <> 2) and (b.wk is null OR b.wk <> 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution. I was stuck in looking a way to replace null in id and category fields when records only present in wk=1 or wk=2. Thank you.

Comment: @Bigyellowbee You are welcome. I tried the query, and the one I had originally produced more rows than you needed. I added a `where` condition at the end to eliminate that problem.

Comment: Appreciate your attitude.